# Replacing string with new value with id/class using javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Need to replace a string and want to edit the css of the new string.

```
var newData = data.replace(/-/gi, ' <span id=\"newCss;\">//</span>');
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: It seems unclear what you're asking. Change the CSS of the new string? Why have you got `newCss` in the span's `id`? Have you meant including it in `style` rather than `id`?

Comment: Yes. Just changing the slashes in other color. I never use inline-css... data.replace(/-/gi, ' <span style=\"color: red;\">//</span>'); You mean like this?

Comment: "Just changing the slashes in other color" – what colour? What other colour? Sorry but I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to achieve? Do you simply want to change the ID of the span?

Comment: I have a string with text. I want to change al the "-" into "//". the "//" needs to be in another color, so I want to replace it and creating an id for changing this afterwards(there is no <span> present).

Comment: Now I finally understand what you mean. Will this `//` be unique on the page? If you want to replace it in several places you should use a class instead of ID.

Comment: multiple but okay. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have semi-colons in id's according to the DOM rules, that might be your issue. Also, `id` should only be used for singular items, so unless you are guaranteed to have only one such dash you are replacing on the page, you should use a class.

Try:

```
var newData = data.replace(/-/gi, ' <span class=\"coloredSlash\">//</span>');
```

and make sure that in your css or `<style>` you have

```
.coloredSlash { color: red; }
```

Then if you want to make changes to its color later, just update your `<style>` element.

Comment: Doesn't work. Example: Jef - Louis - Mike - Charles. With the str.replace like you said the output is: Jef <span class=\"coloredSlash\">//</span> Louis <span class=\"coloredSlash\">//</span> Mike <span class=\"coloredSlash\">//</span> Charles <span class=\"coloredSlash\">//</span>